# WPF ICollectionView Refresh

Tags: wpf, multithreading, collections, refresh

Is there any way how to do

```
ICollectionView.Refresh()
```

or

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(args.NewValue).Refresh();
```

in a **separate thread**?

I know I can use dispatcher, but this collection is binded to a ListView and it throws cross thread Exceptions.

The reason why I need a second thread is, that I have Control which displays a list of IMyItems. When filtering this Collection (by user text change input), I want to be able to display my animation that CollectionView is changing.

Comment: If you're looking to filter this during user input, you should be able to display your animation (begin a storyboard, for instance) when they start typing - no need for a second thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't!

All UI operations *must* happen on the user interface thread, and nearly every call inside of WPF's DispatcherObject (and all controls in that hierarchy) are regularly going to be calling CheckAccess().

You might want to consider using an ObservableCollection to help keep your data up-to-date, if you're doing processing in a background thread or BackgroundWorker.

Comment: OK so the only way to do this is to have an ObservableCollection, that will processed in a background thread? Not the CollectionView!

Comment: Changing an bbservable collection on a background thread will STILL cause your collectionview to go pop...

Answer (score 3):

How about using the Dispatcher to do work with background priority?

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
    () => { CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(args.NewValue).Refresh(); }
);
```

Comment: but that new value is binded to the ListView.. won't it throw an Exception? that this thread is not the owner?

Comment: Well this solution is really working, You just have to be sure that while runing you don't call it again.. you must wait

Comment: Thats true ;) but patience is a virtue they say ;)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that was possible. That's good to know. +1 from me.

Comment: The dispatcher does not execute code in a background thread.  It executes code in the main thread.  The Background priority does not mean Background Thread.  It means the code will be executed in the main thread when the main thread is not too busy.  

If the code you push in the dispatcher is long to execute, it will freeze the UI for the time it executes.

Use the BackgroundWorker to execute code in threads.

Comment: Yes he is right.. it seemed that it works, but Invoke is synchronous.. with that background priority that means, that if i set a gray background while before Refresh(), it works because it has a higher priority. But if I choose an animation, it loads and freezes for the single thread reason.

Answer (score -2):

I hacked up a quick method to invoke actions on wpf dispatchable objects (all wpf controls inherit from [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx))

```
public static void InvokeWpf(DispatcherObject dispatchable, Action action, bool async)
{
    // DispatcherOperationCallback is optimized for wpf invoke calls
    DispatcherOperationCallback toDo = delegate{ action(); return null; };

    if (!dispatchable.CheckAccess())
    {
        if (async) 
            dispatchable.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(toDo, null);
        else
            dispatchable.Dispatcher.Invoke(toDo, null);
    }
    else
    {
        toDo(null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
InvokeWpf(listView, 
       () => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView).Refresh(), 
       false);
```

Comment: I tried your solution (I've made what you propose).. but anyhow it is running in the same thread...

Comment: In what way DispatcherOperationCallback is optimized?

It is just a delegate. Since you already have that 'action' thingy delegate, wrapping it in another delegate is just a waste of space and readability.